# Which MCU characters are shown to be worthy of Mjolnir in the comics?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, avengers-age-of-ultron

Age of Ultron has a scene with [different characters attempting to lift the Mjolnir](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8cUtTBV8Big), with varying degrees of success and failure.

I was wondering which superheroic characters appearing in the Age of Ultron movie (e.g. Black Widow, Hawkeye, Iron Man, Vision, Hulk, Captain America, Scarlet Witch and Quicksilver) have wielded Mjolnir ***in the comic-books***, and which comic-book issues/arcs did they do so in?

Comment: The linked question shows Storm and Rogue wielding Thor's powers: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/211892/why-doesnt-mjolnir-give-captain-america-thor-like-armor

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Black Widow** - Found worthy in "[What if - Age of Ultron #3](http://marvel.wikia.com/What_If%3F_Age_of_Ultron_Vol_1_3)"

[image]

**Captain America** - Found worthy in "[Thor V1. #390](http://marvel.wikia.com/Thor_Vol_1_390)"

[image]

**Iron Man / Tony Stark** - Found (sorta) worthy in "[Millennial Visions 2001](http://www.marvunapp.com/Appendix3/avenhammervisions.htm)"

[image]

**Hawkeye** - Found (sorta) worthy in "[Millennial Visions 2001](http://www.marvunapp.com/Appendix3/avenhammervisions.htm)"

[image]

**Scarlet Witch** - Found (sorta) worthy in "[Millennial Visions 2001](http://www.marvunapp.com/Appendix3/avenhammervisions.htm)"

[image]

**Hulk** - Found worthy (kinda) in "[Indestructible Hulk #6](http://marvel.wikia.com/Indestructible_Hulk_Vol_1_6)"

[image]

Comment: And just a funny one, Superman wielded it. I know not MCU, not even Marvel but I thought that'd be nice to add ;)

Comment: @VincentAdvocaat - OP is asking about Age of Ultron characters.

Comment: So, pretty much everyone.

Comment: @Mooz - Yup. It would actually be easier to list characters who haven't wielded Mjolnir at some point.

Comment: I always wondered how Black Widow could possibly be worthy. Even in her hero days, she was basically an assassin who was being a hero for selfish reasons.

Comment: @Omegacron  -It isn't main continuity. The premise is basically, what if Black Widow *was* worthy...

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "sortas"? Especially the Hulk one.

Comment: @DCShannon - Most of these are "what if" stories. In the case of the cartoonised one, those hammers aren't actualy mjolnir but identical hammers made by Odin to mock Thor (who you can see in the background wielding a small carpenter's hammer). The Hulk one is part of the Marvel! Now! initiative, "*revisioning"* classic characters. Many of those new arcs were dumped when the new Secret Wars storyline became their main canon arc.

Comment: It would seem like those cartoony ones aren't even close enough to merit a "sorta" then, and it sounds like the Hulk one would be on the same level of "sorta" as the Widow one.

Comment: @DCShannon - They're all Mjolnir in a certain sense. The Hulk one was at least part of the main continuity.

Answer (score 5):

**[Thor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thor_(comics))** is worthy in both the MCU and in the comics.

Although it is a common trope for him to be unworthy at some point in the storyline and having to prove himself; it is evident that he is:

- In the [Thor comics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thor_%28Marvel_Comics%29)
- In the [MCU](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Thor)
- Proven to be worthy of wielding [Mjölnir](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mjolnir_(comics)) at some point both media

Comment: For the record, much of the first Thor film revolves around him not being worthy.

Comment: You can argue that it's an incomplete or poor answer, but it's an answer.

Comment: @phantom42 - Yup.

Comment: I admit this answer is a bit tongue-in-cheek, but it stands as technically true. :-p