# You can't wield Mjolnir unless you're worthy, but has anyone ever stopped Thor from wielding it?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, mjolnir

The mighty hammer **[Mjolnir](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mjolnir_(comics))** has a special enchantment placed on it by the uber-Asgardian, **[Odin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odin_(comics))**:

> *Whosoever holds this hammer, if he be worthy, shall possess the power of Thor*

which means that you have to be "worthy" in the eye(s) of **Odin** to *use* the hammer.<sup>[[1]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mjolnir_(comics)#cite_note-Journey_Into_Mystery.27_1962-1)</sup>.

The most notable wielder of the hammer is our very own [Avenger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avengers_(comics)), **[Thor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thor_(Marvel_Comics))**<sub>**#**</sub>, with some others shown to have been worthy through the years<sup>[[2]](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/87846/21267)</sup>.

You can't wield Mjolnir if you're not worthy yourself, but **Is it possible to *stop* Thor from wielding his hammer?**<sub>**^**</sub>. i.e. Can you stop the hammer from going to Thor?

---

<sub>**#** Give or take an instance or two where he's unworthy, and then proves that he's worthy after all.</sub>

**^** I don't mean making Thor unworthy, by doing something like, corrupting him or something, but can someone **physically** stop Thor from grabbing his hammer, without holding his arms or anything?

Comment: This seems like purely speculation to me, but I suppose that if somebody else is also worthy, Thor might not be able to call it out of your hand.

Comment: In *Thor: The Dark World*, Thor is seperated from Mjolnir by the Convergence, which sends him into a different realm. Rather than following Thor into the Convergence, Mjolnir instead flies directly into space. It seems reasonable that the pathfinding element of Mjolnir isn't sufficiently advanced to cope with the notion of multiple realms, so you could quite easily seperate them that way.

Comment: Surely if you yourself were worthy you could just take the hammer and not give it back?

Comment: Considering that Vision is able to lift Mjolnir in Avengers 2, he could conceivably hang on to it and fly off somewhere. Thor can't fly without his hammer, so he'd be unable to chase after Vision. This is a comment only because 1) Vision doesn't attempt this and 2) we have no idea what would happen if Thor tried to recall Mjolnir while in Vision's possession. But, it is at least plausible that Vision could prevent Thor from wielding it by wielding it himself.

Comment: This isn't really relevant to the question at hand, but it is too ridiculous not to share.  [Superman wielding Mjolnir AND Captain America's shield, and smashing a hole in the moon.](https://awesomecomicbookpages.files.wordpress.com/2014/10/supes-thor-hammer-cap-shield.jpg)

Comment: @WadCheber that scene looks like someone had a teenager power orgasm when coming up with it...

Answer (score 10):

In the Marvel Comics Magneto is able to stop the flight of Mjolnir using his *magnetic repellor field*, so it is possible to prevent Thor from wielding the hammer.

> And just as Magneto says, the flying hammer suddenly **stops**, held by a power beyond mere description!

[image: From the comics. Magneto stops Mjolnir.]

But I'm not sure whether this qualifies as *physical*, which you asked for.

Comment: Physics, physical, close enough

Answer (score 7):

Beta Ray Bill is a non-Asgardian who has wielded Mjolnir and actually wrestled with Thor over control of it. He ended up getting his own hammer called Stormbreaker I believe it was called. But he stopped Thor from wielding it by wielding it himself, if that answers the question

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_Ray_Bill for anyone who hasn't heard of this guy before.

Comment: Beta Ray Bill is the most underrated comic book character of all time.

Answer (score 5):

Conveniently enough, this has happened a couple of times in the current run of *Thor*.  In issue #2, Mjolnir gets trapped in a room that has vibranium core with adamantium-plating walls (the room is a vault that also has magical wards on it, but those don't seem relevant).  It's unable to break through the door, but it tries and tries.  In issue #7, the Destroyer (which was remoted controlled) grabs the hammer, and attacks her with it.

In the Marvel Cinematic Universe, the closest we get to this is in *Thor: The Dark World*.  During a battle with Thor, Kurse knocks Mjolnir away as Thor is calling it to him.

Answer (score 4):

In Age of Ultron, we see Quicksilver in hyperspeed watching the hammer fly by in slow motion. He then tries to grab it (for whatever reason) which he probably thinks would stop the flight. Instead when he grabs the hammer, it takes him with it.

This is one point that could prove, that no lifeform could in any way affect Mjolnir's flight, or position (it cannot be moved or stopped).

The only way i can think of is Vibranium. Captain America was able to withstand a punch with Mjolnir by blocking it with his Shield (with catastrophic effect). So building a vibranium case around Mjolnir could do the job. Since it's a rare metal it would be very difficult though, since when the hammer is called, the vibranium case would fly with it.

Apart from cutting off Thor's hands (see the Dark World), killing him or paralyzing him, i think there is no "physical" way of stopping Thor to wield his Hammer.

Comment: In AoU Cap seems to be able to lift it, though he stops and fakes that he can't do it but the face of Thor is priceless.

Comment: @Thomas That's a fan theory (and one that I love), but it's just a fan theory.  The official story is that Cap couldn't lift it.

Comment: At no point did it even seem to imply that cap was faking it.

Comment: But Mjolnir moved when Cap tried to lift it, even though just a little bit and Thor's face was in shock.

Comment: That's because he's a little bit worthy ;-) Of all the avengers (except Thor), Captain America is the only one who "could" be worthy enough to lift the hammer. Thats why it moved a little bit. The shock on Thors face revealed that he thought for a second, that if anyone could lift the Hammer, it would be Cap.

Answer (score 0):

There is an old comic where Thor is being mind controlled. He fights Captain America and is astounded that a mere mortal is so tricksome. Captain America gets Thor to throw his hammer and he deflects it by throwing his shield! Thor tries to get his hammer back (not sure why it doesn't return to his hand) but Cap keeps interfering. Tripping Thor etc. Until the old Curse triggers. The Curse being that if Thor doesn't hold Mjolnir, he changes back into his human form of Donald Blake (A curse from Odin to teach his son humility). Thor is then knocked unconscious by a shield slam from Cap! Cap then says ,"I always wondered why Thor never let his hammer around, considering no one can lift it. He never imagined that Thor would have such a weak alter ego"