# What characters from the Marvel Classic Comic Universe are known to have lifted Mjolnir?

Tags: marvel, mjolnir

I know that Beta Ray Bill, Cap'n and Storm have lifted Mjolnir at some point in the classic comic universe.

Excluding

1. omnipotent beings (like Odin)
2. other comic series (like 2099, ultimates, etc)
3. Thor's alter egos
4. What-if comics and other alternate-universe crossovers

What other characters from classic earth-616 have lifted Mjolnir?

Bonus points for comic issue reference.

Comment: Odin isn't omnipotent. For one, he's dead.

Comment: I know she's DC and not Marvel, but Wonder Woman picked it up in the Marvel vs DC crossover series.

Comment: [This article](http://www.ign.com/articles/2014/09/30/12-other-characters-who-have-lifted-thors-hammer-mjolnir) covers a few characters who have been able to wield it.  Some of them aren't truly canon to the present universe.

Comment: See also [@Thaddeus's answer here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87008/what-makes-this-character-worthy-to-lift-thors-hammer-mjolnir/87086#87086).

Comment: @gowenfawr had to upvote him.

Comment: See [Richard's comment](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87846/which-mcu-characters-are-shown-to-be-worthy-of-mjolnir-in-the-comics?rq=1#comment193657_87848): "It would actually be easier to list characters who haven't wielded Mjolnir at some point."

Answer (score 3):

Excluding all the ones you have already mentioned / excluded i can think of:

- Eric Masterson lifted it in The Mighty Thor Vol. 1 No. 432 before getting his own weapon a mace and taking the name Thunderstrike
- Jane Foster lifted it to become the Goddess of thunder in Thor Vol. 4
  No. 1.
- Throg (Simon Walterson aka Puddlegulp) hasn't lifted the real Mjolnir, but a sliver of it, which then became Frogjolnir. It has the fractional power of Mjolnir and the same magical restriction of Worthiness. While a bit of a joke character, he's still in 616 proper canon.

Comment: Added the mighty Throg. Not to be confused with Thorse.