# Could Cap have gotten​ Thor's armour too?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*, when Cap managed to wield Mjölnir and manipulate lightning, did that mean that Cap could have theoretically used the armour that Thor himself summons when using his hammer? As seen in the first *Thor* movie, he only gets the armour when the hammer deems him worthy.

Comment: Dupe I guess https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/211892/why-doesnt-mjolnir-give-captain-america-thor-like-armor

Comment: Dupe imo, as @SteveHarrington points out. However, we cannot close either until the other has a valid answer with positive votes I guess.

Comment: I don't agree that it's a dupe as that question specifies comics and this one specifies MCU

Comment: Voting to close as primarily opinion-based

Comment: @Gothamite24 - Why so? It's not opinion-based at all!

Comment: I disagree. So far, in this universe, Thor and Vision are the only 2 characters to have extended use of the hammer before Steve does. And considering that we won't know what will happen with Jane Foster for further information until the release of Thor: Love and Thunder, the question also violates the Future Works Policy

Comment: @Gothamite24 Just because there is potential information in the future doesn't mean this violates the FWP. In fact we probably have all the information about Steve we can get and the question is about past events not upcoming ones. This certainly doesn't violate the FWP.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot-I'm sorry, but it does. The fact of the matter is that Thor for the most part is the only character so far to wield the hammer over an extended period of time, whereas both Vision and Cap were instances that were quite brief in comparison. Due to Love and Thunder primarily set to focus on the Jane Foster Thor storyline from the comics is an event where someone is wielding Mjolnir in a Future Work (in this case, Thor: Love and Thunder, which has yet to be released).

Answer (score 4):

## We don't know but probably not

In the MCU we have only seen 3 beings wield Mjolnir (excluding Odin as he placed the enchantment): Thor, Vision and Cap. Of these 3 only Thor gets the armour and he only gets it that first time in *Thor*. After that he never gets the armour on if he isn't wearing it again. As we can see below in *Avengers: Endgame* when he travels to Asgard with Rocket.

Vision is a bit of an odd case but he is made from the regeneration cradle which does print living tissue.

> **Dr. Helen Cho:** The regeneration cradle prints tissue, it can't build a living body.
>
> **Ultron:** It can, you can. You lack the materials. You're a brilliant woman, Helen. But we all have room to improve
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Age of Ultron*</sub>

As he is a living being but not exactly 100% "living" it would seem he should also get the chance to receive the armour but again he does not.

Then of course we have Steve, who, as we know, does not get the armour in *Avengers: Endgame* when he wields Mjolnir against Thanos. This all points to the fact that Steve can't get the armour but there is nothing explicit on the matter.

In *Avengers: Endgame* Thor "summons" the armour to himself before himself, Steve and Tony engage with Thanos. This makes it seem like getting the armour is more of an extra ability rather than an intrinsic ability to the hammer and being worthy. Therefore, it would seem that Cap did not get the armour because he either didn't know how or didn't want to.

---

It's also worth noting in the comics [all the times we've seen him wield Mjolnir](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/217579/58193) that I'm aware of he never gets the armour. For example, the very first time he does this, I believe, is in *Thor* Issue 390 when Captain America wields Mjolnir in order to give it back to Thor.

[image: Thor and Cap hold Mjolnir together]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

---

I think it is worth noting that Jane Foster will become Thor in *Thor: Love and Thunder* and from the promotional images she is wearing the armour. However, she is becoming **Thor** and not just someone wielding Mjolnir so there appears to be a difference here. The exact nature of this hasn't been revealed yet of course as the film isn't out yet but it is worth thinking about.

[image: Love and Thunder poster]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

Comment: I think it's worth noting that there might be a slight distinction between becoming worthy at the time you wield Mjolnir (Thor in _Thor_) and always being worthy and wielding Mjolnir later on (Cap in _Endgame_, Thor in _Endgame_) but that seems very speculative.

Comment: Doesnt he get the armour when they see Thanos sitting there in Endgame after he bombed the facility ? He doesnt have it on and then suddenly he does ?

Comment: @GamerGypps You know what I never noticed, Yes he does and the way it happens it looks like Thor summons it, rather than it being attached to the hammer directly.