# Why didn't this happen to Captain America in Avengers: Endgame?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame, mjolnir, thor-love-and-thunder

In *Thor: Love and Thunder*, we saw that

> when Jane wielded Mjölnir her outfit transforms into a much more Thor-like one.

In *Avengers: Endgame*, Captain America wielded Mjölnir, however that didn't happen to him (he retained his normal outfit). Why is this?

Comment: Because he already looked so darn good in the other one...

Comment: It's probably a by-choice kind of thing, or maybe only for people who are Asgardians (by birth or otherwise; Jane ends up in Valhalla, so there's got to be something said about it by that)

Comment: The same thing happened in the comics, and an explanation for that was never provided to the best of my knowledge, so I'd be surprised if an official explanation exists for the MCU, though fans are likely to come up with their own theories. There's actually a lot we don't know about how Mjolnir works, like what specifically makes people 'worthy' or 'unworthy' and the precise mechanism Mjolnir uses to prevent unworthy people from lifting it.

Comment: Possibly it would have if he had been in civilian clothes.  When he was already dressed for war, the hammer had no need to dress him again.

Comment: Of course, it doesn't 'dress' Thor either...

Comment: [Related but comics based](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/211892/58193).

Answer (score 5):

Possessing "The Power of Thor"<sub><sup><sup>TM</sup></sup></sub> and holding Mjölnir or Stormbreaker appears to bestow a range of abilities on the wielder. This includes the ability to create a Thor-style battlesuit. We see this in both *Thor: Ragnarok* and several times in *Thor: Love and Thunder* when both Jane and Thor put on Thor suits.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Being clothed by the Power of Thor<sub><sup><sup>TM</sup></sup></sub> is definitely one that requires **an intentional decision on the part of the wielder of said power**. Thor only gets his battlesuit on when he wants to, not simply when he holds Stormbreaker or Mjölnir. Presumably Cap'n America could have had his very own Thor suit if he'd wanted one.

Comment: Another good data point here is all the kids at the end of *Love and Thunder*, who don't get battlesuits.

Comment: @MartianInvader - Their Thor powers seem to have come with a range of limitations

Comment: FWIW the one caveat to this would be the end of _Thor_ IIRC and presumably also somewhat Jane the first time around.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - The latter case we can put down to Mjolnir being overly helpful